# AutoResize MainWindow after user resizes window

Tags: c#, wpf, autoresize

I have a `Window` defined as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="AutomatedSQLMigration.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        SizeToContent="Height"        
        DataContext="{Binding MainPageViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
    <DockPanel Name="MasterDockPanel">
       ...
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

I have a number of tabs in a tab control and the window correctly resizes the height to fit the content of the selected tab as long as the user does not change the window size.  Once the user changes the window size manually, the window will not resize itself to fit the content of the selected tab.

What can I do to get the window to resize automatically even after the user has manually changed the size?

Comment: Since you are speaking of tab controls, why don't you include them in the XAML shown?

Comment: Off-topic: As a user, I would probably become really annoyed to watch the window resize *itself* right after I went to the trouble of *manually* changing its window's size. Either make the window resizable, and let the user determine the window size; or make it non-resizable, and let the window choose.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you required behavior outside the box, so I can see these solutions:

- Set the minimum Height for the `Window` (like this `<Window MinHeight="150" ...`), in order the user can not change the Height is less than the specified minimum content of `TabControl`. I think this is the most simple and reliable solution.
- Use a hack like this:

`XAML`

```
<Window x:Class="AutoResizeProblem.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        SizeToContent="Height">

    <DockPanel Name="MasterDockPanel" Background="Aquamarine">
        <TabControl SelectionChanged="TabControl_SelectionChanged">
            <TabItem Header="Test1">
                <TextBlock Name="Test1Content" Background="Red" Height="100">TEST1</TextBlock>
            </TabItem>

            <TabItem Header="Test2">
                <TextBlock>TEST2</TextBlock>
            </TabItem>

            <TabItem Header="Test3">
                <TextBlock>TEST3</TextBlock>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>       
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

`Code-behind`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    double _initWindowHeight = 0;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _initWindowHeight = this.Height;
    }

    private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_initWindowHeight > 0)
            this.Height = _initWindowHeight;            
    }
}
```

In this case, you save the initial Height of the `Window` in *`Loaded`* event. Then, when you change tabs (*`SelectionChanged`* event) is assigned to the saved value for the `Window`.